# automated mysql maintaince

Tags: mysql, maintenance

Is there a script doing mysql maintenance ?

or

how can i make it manually, using cron tab ?

and

what steps should a good mysql maintenance run ?

(MyISAM)

Comment: Let's start with you defining what you mean by "maintenance".

Comment: i am newbie on db stuff, so i think i mean  table optimizations, checks, repairs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysqlcheck`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) in crontab works well.  Periodically review the logs.

There's an important caveat in the documentation:

> Each table is locked and therefore
>   unavailable to other sessions while it
>   is being processed, although for check
>   operations, the table is locked with a
>   READ lock onlyREAD lock only

Here's how I've used it:

```
mysqlcheck -u $DB_USER -p"$DB_PASS" --all-databases > /root/mysql_backups/check_errors-${DATESTAMP}.log
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the best opensource and used code is this for simple backups
[automysqlbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/)

It can make simple full backups and have them rotated automatically for you..

You could also instead consider using LVM on your mysql directory and making backups on the fly without needing to locktables..

MyISAM tables are table locking, not row locking, so during a mysql backup some tables are not writable..

Unless you are having extremely high throughput, just go with the link i gave you :D

Comment: i am already using automysqlbackup, i meant other maintenance process like table optimizations, checks, repairs etc...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using FULLTEXT indexes, you should really convert to InnoDB.  MyISAM is old and **will** corrupt your data given the slightest excuse, not to mention the fact that it's slow.  Conversion is as simple as:

1. Making sure that you're running a 5.1 or newer version of MySQL.
2. Issuing `ALTER TABLE (tablename) ENGINE=InnoDB` for each table.
3. (If running your own MySQLd) Changing your my.cnf to have space allocated to innodb_buffer_pool; you can swap whatever space you've dedicated to key_buffer out, since InnoDB doesn't use that.

If you insist on using MyISAM, a simple "mysqlcheck -A --optimize" or similar should do what you seem to want.

Comment: my version is 5.1.51 somehow "ALTER TABLE (tablename) ENGINE=InnoDB" doesnt work when i execute it from phpmyadmin ?